# Is there any way to connect using python a PLC FX3U using ENET ADP and read registers(D)?

Tags: python, ethernet, plc

Using Python i have been trying for days(pymodbus, pymodbus3, pymodbusTCP) to conect to a PLC(FX3U-48M) using ENET ADP over Ethernet and the device connects but cannot read any register:

```
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

def validator(instance):
    if not instance.isError():
        '''.isError() implemented in pymodbus 1.4.0 and above.'''
        decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(
            instance.registers,
            byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Little
        )
        return float('{0:.2f}'.format(decoder.decode_32bit_float()))

    else:
        # Error handling.
        print("There isn't the registers, Try again.")
        return None


client = ModbusTcpClient('192.168.1.250', port= 5556)  # Specify the port.
connection = client.connect()

if connection:
    request = client.read_holding_registers(0x9C40, 0x02, unit=0x01)  # Specify the unit.
    data = validator(request)
    print(data)

    client.close()

else:
    print('Connection lost, Try again')

Result:
C:\Users\Administrator\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/PythonProjects/modbus3.py
There isn't the registers, Try again.
None

Process finished with exit code 0








Also i Try Thisone:
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

host = '192.168.1.250'
port = 5556

client = ModbusTcpClient(host, port)
client.connect()

#Register address 0x102A (4138dec) with a word count of 1
#Value - MODBUS/TCP Connections
#Access - Read
#Description - Number of TCP connections

request = client.read_holding_registers(100,8,unit=1)
#response = client.execute(request)

print(request)
#print response.registers
#print(response.getRegister(12))

client.close()
```

The Result:
C:\Users\Administrator\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/PythonProjects/MitsubishiPLC.py
Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] Incomplete message received, expected at least 8 bytes (0 received)

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: It might be useful to include the output which you are getting.

Comment: Yes sorry,  This :   C:\Users\Administrator\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/PythonProjects/modbus3.py
There isn't the registers, Try again.
None

Process finished with exit code 0